# jQuery autocomplete not works with remote data from ashx

Tags: vb.net, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, ashx

I use a jQuery autocomplete with an ASHX as source. But every request throws an error with number 200.

My JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#username input[type = "text"]').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "UserName.ashx?term=" + request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Value
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="username">
    <asp:Label Text="User name" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
</div>
```

ASHX:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"

    Try
        Dim oList As New List(Of ResultItem)

        For Each File As System.IO.FileInfo In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(ApplicationInfo.Settings.AbsoluteUserConfigPath).GetFiles(context.Request.QueryString("term") & "*.xml")
            oList.Add(New ResultItem With {.Value = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.Name, File.Extension & "$", String.Empty)})
        Next

        context.Response.Write(New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(oList))
    Catch ex As Exception
        context.Response.Clear()
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500
        context.Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

With static content it works fine but with this request I get the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`.

The resulting JSON looks like

```
[
    {"Value":"Item 1","Name":"","Description":""},
    {"Value":"Item 2","Name":"","Description":""},
    {"Value":"Item 3","Name":"","Description":""},
    {"Value":"Item 4","Name":"","Description":""}
]
```

and should be valid.

Any idea why it does not work? What is the unexpected character?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the source and the JSON and then works it.

```
$(function () {
    $('#username input[type = "text"]').autocomplete({
        source: "UserName.ashx"
    });
}
```

```
[
    {"object":"Item 1","label":"","Description":""},
    {"object":"Item 2","label":"","Description":""},
    {"object":"Item 3","label":"","Description":""},
    {"object":"Item 4","label":"","Description":""}
]
```